# Как можно определить, что элемент кастомный?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Коллеги, можно ли определить, что тот или иной элемент кастомный?

К примеру:

```js
/* Так, естественно можно захватить элмемент */

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]);

console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('zinaida')[0]);
```

```html
<!--есть в DOM элементы-->
<zinaida></zinaida>
<pavel></pavel>

<div></div>
<span></span>
<p></p>
```

А как я могу захватить все кастомные элементы, именно кастомные...

В данном случае получить массив из элементов `<zinaida></zinaida> <pavel></pavel>`

Хочу сразу отметить тот факт, что присвоить им какой либо `class` или другой какой либо атрибут и определить по `class` или атрибуту, я и сам соображу...

Такой метод, как создать некий массив из всех элементов и сверять с этим массивом, тоже не нужен, тем более, что я уже так делал...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28210364/4794368 следующий за этим - тоже оригинален, ну и далее вариант для 2017 года

Comment: _как я могу захватить все кастомные элементы_ - никак.

Comment: @Grundy, благодарю...  Лаконично и ясно...))

Comment: А если попробовать через `regexp` всего `html`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, Ну костыли можно разные придумать...Меня интересовало, может быть есть какой-нить встроенный метод...

Comment: Встроенных методов нету. Или я не знаю о таких...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
const elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');

const isUnknown = function(value) {
  return value instanceof HTMLUnknownElement;
};


for (let el of elems) {
  if (isUnknown(el)) {
    el.classList.add('unknown');
  } else {

    el.classList.add('no-unknown');
  }
};
```

```css
.unknown {
  color: red;
}

.no-unknown {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!--есть в DOM элементы-->
<zinaida>zinaida</zinaida>
<pavel>pavel</pavel>

<div>div</div>
<span>span</span>
<p>p</p>
```

А еще есть второй вариант. По требованиям спецификации кастомные элементы надо создавать через дефис.

[Можно почитать тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/webcomponent-core#%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-custom-elements)

Например так:

> `<ce-zinaida>zinaida</ce-zinaida>`

И тут оказывается, что пример выше не будет работать с касотмным элементом с дефисом. И выйти из ситуации можно так:

```js
const elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (let el of elems) {
  if (!(el.__proto__ instanceof HTMLElement)) {
    el.classList.add('custom');
  } else {
    el.classList.add('no-custom');
  }
};
```

```css
.custom {
  color: red;
}

.no-custom {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!--есть в DOM элементы-->
<ce-zinaida>zinaida</ce-zinaida>
<ce-pavel>pavel</ce-pavel>
<div>div</div>
<span>span</span>
<p>p</p>
```

---

Этот блок добавлен автором вопроса.
Так как при использовании данного примера, выявлен `БАГ`. Почему-то `'элемент- NAV` определяется как `custom`

> Коллеги, предлагаю, если кто выявит еще какие проблемы, дополнить
>   ответ

```js
const elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (let el of elems) {
  if (!(el.__proto__ instanceof HTMLElement)) {
    el.classList.add('custom');
  } else {
    el.classList.add('no-custom');
  }
};
```

```css
.custom {
  color: red;
}

.no-custom {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<zi-na>Это Zina</zi-na>
<nav>Это NAV</nav>
<div>Это div</div>
<p>Это p</p>
<span>Это span</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

Посмотрев примеры выше, пришла еще одна идея. Раз кастомные элементы  обязательно надо создавать через дефис, почему бы тогда не проверить наличие дефиса в `tagName`

Вариант первый - регулярное выражения:

```js
const elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (let i of elems) {
  let reg = new RegExp(/-/g);
  console.log(i.localName + ' - ' + (reg.test(i.localName) ? 'da' : 'net'));
}
```

```html
<ce-zinaida>zinaida</ce-zinaida>
<ce-pavel>pavel</ce-pavel>
<div>div</div>
<span>span</span>
<p>p</p>
```

Вариант два:

```js
const elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (let i of elems) {
  if (i.localName.indexOf('-') !== -1) {

    console.log(i.localName + ' - da')
  } else {
    console.log(i.localName + ' - net')
  }
}
```

```html
<ce-zinaida>zinaida</ce-zinaida>
<ce-pavel>pavel</ce-pavel>
<div>div</div>
<span>span</span>
<p>p</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Похоже что у кастомных (не зарегистрированных) элементов прототип `HTMLUnknownElement` - тогда как у стандартных прототипом является его предок `HTMLElement`, а у зарегистрированных свои прототипы.

Соответственно, определить незарегистрированный кастомный элемент можно по этому признаку, выражением

```
element instanceof HTMLUnknownElement
```

---

Под спойлером ниже, пример кода с простейшим методом `Element.isCustom()`, и функцией поиска кастомных элементов по селектору - `getCustomElements()`:

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.isCustom = function () {
  return this instanceof HTMLUnknownElement; 
}; 

function getCustomElements(selector, fromElement = null) {
  let result = [], 
      allEls = (fromElement || document).querySelectorAll(selector); 
  for (let el of allEls) { 
    if (el.isCustom())
      result.push(el); 
  }
  return result; 
}

let cntnr = document.querySelector('#container'); 
cntnr.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let els = document.querySelectorAll('.found'); 
  els.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('found'));
  let selector = e.target.dataset.selector; 
  if (!selector)
    return; 
  els = getCustomElements(selector); 
  els.forEach(el => el.classList.add('found')); 
});
```

```css
#container { height: calc(100vh - 10px); }

#container * {
  display: inline-block; 
  min-width: 40px; 
  line-height: 2em; 
  margin: 4px; padding: 10px; 
  font: 16px sans-serif; color: #000; 
  border: 1px dashed #aaa; 
}

#container > span {
  background-color: #777; 
  border: none; 
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  color: #fff; 
  cursor: pointer;
}

#container .found {
  border: 1px solid #d44;
  color: #d44;
}

#container test.found {
  border: 1px solid #2a2;
  color: #2a2;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span data-selector="*">Найти все кастомные</span>
  <span data-selector="test">Найти только &lt;test&gt;</span>
  <br>
  <div>div</div>
  <zinaida>zinaida</zinaida>
  <test>test 1</test>
  <pavel>
    pavel
    <some>some</some>
    <span>span</span>
    <test>test 2</test>
  </pavel>
  <p>p</p>
</div>
```

Необязательным параметром `fromElement` задается тот элемент, от которого будет выполняться поиск ("вниз" по DOM).
Клик по области результата сбрасывает классы с найденных элементов.
В целом, код достаточно простой, думаю что он не требует подробных пояснений :)

---

Источники инфы:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/27334365
[HTMLUnknownElement (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement)